# О заболевших оспой. Как понимать сообщение?

Tags: названия, терминология, словосочетания, смысл

> Больше всего заразившихся оспой обезьян в Великобритании — 524 случая.

Как избежать двусмысленности, заложенной в этой фразе?

Comment: А какая двусмысленность здесь?

Comment: На нет и суда нет.

Comment: Shampar, я вас не очень понимаю

Comment: *Не очень понимать* значит как-то понимать. А что именно не понимаете, можете сказать?

Comment: Где двусмысленность?

Comment: Она — в слове *заразившихся*, в его трактовке, а также в термине *оспа обезьян*, его возвможном восприятии как пары связанных слов.

Answer (score 3):

Элементарно, Ватсон!

*Больше всего заразившихся обезьяньей оспой* (или *случаев заражения обезьяньей оспой*) *в Великобритании: 524.*

Comment: Логично: свиным, птичим гриппом...

Comment: Как у меня, тоже выражаются. «Вспы́шка о́спы обезья́н в 2022 году́ — вспышка в 2022 году зооантропонозного вирусного заболевания обезьяньей оспы, наблюдается в ряде государств». https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD_(2022)

Answer (score 2):

- Больше всего случаев заражения оспой обезьян — в Великобритании: 524.
- Больше всего жертв оспы обезьян — в Великобритании: 524.

Как-то так, пожалуй.